# In which template event can I hide elements from the main template (Meteor)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, meteor, meteor-blaze

I've got a main template, and two that are displayed via (Iron) routing:

```
<template name="main">
  <div id="templateMain" name="templateMain">
    <a href="nfnoscar">The Legend of NFN Oscar</a>
    <br/>
    <a href="nfnoscarsdonut">NFN Oscar's donut</a>
  </div>
</template>

<template name="nfnoscar">
  <h1>The True Story of NFN Oscar</h1>
  <h2 class="monospaceboldsmallcap">Come and Listen to a Story About a Man without a first Name</h2>
  <p>Many people wonder how it can be that NFN (No First Name) Oscar Herrera does not have a first name.</p>
  <p>Finally, the secret of his birth name and its subsequent alteration can be revealed.</p>
   . . .
```

The challenge is that I want to hide the two links/anchor tags from the main template when the other templates are displaying. I have a "hide" CSS class that hides an element with that class is attached to it.

What event can I tap into (no pun intended) to accomplish this?

I tried this:

```
  Template.nfnoscar.onRendered({
    $('#templateMain').addClass('hide');
  });

  Template.nfnoscarsdonut.onRendered({
    $('#templateMain').addClass('hide');
  });

  Template.main.onRendered({
    $('#templateMain').removeClass('hide');
  });
```

...but I get err msgs on compilation; I don't think I can reference an element in the main template from the other templates, anyway (or maybe that's my whole problem). The err I see in the console/command prompt (Windows 7) is:

```
=> Errors prevented startup:

   While processing files with ecmascript (for target web.browser):
   platypus.js:8:6: platypus.js: Unexpected token (8:6)

   While processing files with ecmascript (for target os.windows.x86_32):
   platypus.js:8:6: platypus.js: Unexpected token (8:6)

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

So what needs to change/how can I hide those initial links when routing to them?

Here's my entire *.js file:

```
Router.route('/');
Router.route('/nfnoscar');
Router.route('/nfnoscarsdonut');

if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.nfnoscar.onRendered({
    $('#templateMain').addClass('hide');
  });

  Template.nfnoscarsdonut.onRendered({
    $('#templateMain').addClass('hide');
  });

  Template.main.onRendered({
    $('#templateMain').removeClass('hide');
  });

}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

So the complained-about line:character (8:6) is the "(" after the "$" here:

```
Template.nfnoscar.onRendered({
  $('#templateMain').addClass('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error. In JavaScript, you can't just pass a code block to a function: you need to explicitly pass an anonymous function, like so:

```
Template.nfnoscar.onRendered(function() {
  $('#templateMain').addClass('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This approach of hiding the classes based on the template, doesn't feel like the most Meteor way to approach the problem. That being said, I will suggest a more meteor way.

Instead of manipulating the DOM and hiding or showing classes, why not display the templates you want based on your route? (based on http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/iron-router-tutorial)

Step1: Set up your routes.

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});
Router.route('/', {
  name: 'main',
  template: 'main'
});
Router.route('/nfnoscar' {
  name: 'nfnoscar',
  template: 'nfnoscar'
});
Router.route('/nfnoscarsdonut' {
  name: 'nfnoscarsdonut',
  template: 'nfnoscarsdonut'
});
```

Step 2) Organize your templates. *When you use > yield it only displays the template described in the route.*

```
<template name='layout'>
  {{> yield}}
</template>

<template name="main">
  <div id="templateMain" name="templateMain">
    <a href="nfnoscar">The Legend of NFN Oscar</a>
    <br/>
    <a href="nfnoscarsdonut">NFN Oscar's donut</a>
  </div>
</template>
<template name="nfnoscar">
  <h1>The True Story of NFN Oscar</h1>
  <h2 class="monospaceboldsmallcap">Come and Listen to a Story About a Man Named NFN</h2>
  <p>Many people wonder how it can be that NFN (No First Name) Oscar Herrera cannot have a first name.</p>
  <p>Finally, the secret of his birth name and its subsequent alteration can be revealed.</p>
```

Step 3) Now that you have a layout template, if there is content you want to display on ever page, it's very easy.

```
<template name='layout'>
  {{> navbar}} // Will display a navbar template on every page
  {{> yield}}
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch; I did implement your idea, and it's working great! There were a couple of minor typos (missing quote, a couple of missing commas) but all easily fixed. Thanks again, Paul!